# Will Sram GX Eagle grip shift trigger work with 11sp cassette?

Tags: sram

Will Sram GX Eagle grip shift trigger work with 11sp cassette? Is it possible to adjust it so that one click in shifter is just useless. I am upgrading my transsmision. I can't afford buying whole eagle set at once (power meter is more important now ;) ) but this solution seems a little more forward-looking.

Comment: And what derailleur?

Comment: I would guess not because the 12 speed sprockets are likely closer together than the 11 speed sprockets. You also have to consider the pull ration of the 12 speed vs 11 speed derailleur. *However*, it's possible that  SRAM kept the same spacing and widened the cassette.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus GX Eagle too. Only sprocket and chain from 11 speed.

Comment: Yep. As @nollak says in his answer it will not work. In general, 10, 11 and 12 speed have no cross compatibility because of the different sprocket spacings, shifter cable pulls and derailleur pull ratios to get these systems to work, for both Shimano and SRAM.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it will not work due to the cassette spacing, even using an 12 speed shifter and derailleur, it will not shift correctly due to the increased space of the 11sp cassette which has 3.8mm between cogs while the 12sp cassette has 3.65mm between cogs.

> [For a 12sp cassette] The spacing between cogs has been reduced, from 3.8 mm to 3.65 mm, and the 50 tooth cog cups the drive body more, thus bringing it closer to the spokes
>
> ....The shifter had to be redesigned to provide for 12 clicks and to incorporate **revised cable pull** to deal with the narrower cog spacing.

[Source](http://fitwerx.com/sram-xx1-eagle-sram-x01-eagle-1x12-drivetrains/)

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. The 12-Speed shifter won't work with the 11-speed deraileur.

According to SRAM on compatibility between 11-/12-speed setups:
Eagle™ chainrings are 11-speed compatible. You can use an Eagle™ chainring on an existing XX1, X01 X1, GX or NX drivetrain. However, traditional SRAM X-SYNC™ 11-Speed rings are not designed for use with Eagle™ drivetrains.

(source: https://sram.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002311394-What-Eagle-parts-are-cross-compatible-with-existing-11-speed-SRAM-components- )

So I think the cable actuation is actually different and the only thing that can be used on both is the chainring.

Comment: 'Link only' answers are discouraged here as they are prone to breaking - please paste in the essence of the information of the link and provide the link for those wishing more detail, so if the link disappears the answer remains valuable.

Comment: You are totally correct, but what happens when that website gets reorganised or goes offline?

Comment: Yeah done that. It is a pretty short answer from SRAM anyways.